# Monitoring Webservices on Domino Server 8.5.3

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm trying to find a way to monitor the actual XML being generated and received with some Webservices I am painfully trying to implement on Domino 8.5.3

[SoapLog, as mentioned by Julian Robichaux](http://www.nsftools.com/tools/soaplog.htm) does not seem to work anymore.

The particular case I have here is that I am accessing, server to server (because it's an HTTPS Call), an external Webservice with a Java Web Service Consumer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wireshark? https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: can't install it on my server (I'm in a bank right now)

Comment: I'm secretly hoping for a notes.ini entry JAVA_LOG_WEBSERVICES=1

Comment: What type of client are you using for testing? Can you get access to the XML that way? I've managed with a .NET client that I built, though I do recall it wasn't all that easy to figure out and I don't recall the details. I've also used the free version of SoapUI a bit.

Comment: It's a web service consumer. I generally use SoapUI for testing web service providers that I create on the domino server, but here I'm stumped.